# How to configure the web page link in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I would like to ask a stupid question because I don't have a deeply understanding of administration and jenkins.

I have created a new git `branch foo` out going from an existing project `branch baar` and now I would like to deploy this `foo branch` with jenkins job. For that reasdon I have created a new jenkins job `foo-job` by copying an existing one job `baar-job` and I have just changed the branch configuration in the new job to be `foo-branch`.

It's actually like this: when `baar-job` run seccuessfully, we can call the project web page on the link `http://maschine-IP:8080/project/`.

My question is how to configure `this project link` in the new created job for the `new created foo-branch`? Will it be automatically h`ttp://maschine-IP:8080/project/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins creates job URL's according to this pattern:
    http://maschine-IP:8080/${job name}

Then, the URL for the newly created job will be according to the new job's name.
I recommend not to touch this configuration